# Failed to import Azure table (AzCopy)

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-table-storage, azcopy

I have an Azure Tables and their backups in the Blob Storage.

[image] [image]

When I trying to restore it using AzCopy some are restored but some are got an error.

**Success**

```
[2018/05/29 12:01:49.463+03:00][VERBOSE] 6.1.0 : AzCopy /Source:https://arenaxtablesbackup.blob.core.windows.net/arenaxstorage/2018-05-28 /Dest:https://arenaxstoragedev.table.core.windows.net/LeaderboardDaily /SourceKey:****** /Destkey:****** /Manifest:arenaxstorage_LeaderboardDaily.manifest /EntityOperation:InsertOrReplace /Z /V
[2018/05/29 12:01:52.531+03:00][VERBOSE] Uploaded entities: 0    Downloaded blobs: 1, transferred bytes: 191 B
[2018/05/29 12:01:52.758+03:00] Validating the integrity of data file list...
[2018/05/29 12:01:52.974+03:00] Validation of data file list passed.
[2018/05/29 12:01:53.208+03:00] 
Transfer summary:
-----------------
Total entities transferred: 0
Elapsed time:               00.00:00:03
[2018/05/29 12:04:57.932+03:00] >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
[2018/05/29 12:04:57.937+03:00][VERBOSE] 6.1.0 : AzCopy /Source:https://arenaxtablesbackup.blob.core.windows.net/arenaxstorage/2018-05-28 /Dest:https://arenaxstoragedev.table.core.windows.net/LeaderboardUser /SourceKey:****** /Destkey:****** /Manifest:arenaxstorage_LeaderboardUser.manifest /EntityOperation:InsertOrReplace /Z /V
[2018/05/29 12:05:01.189+03:00][VERBOSE] Uploaded entities: 0    Downloaded blobs: 1, transferred bytes: 209 B
[2018/05/29 12:05:01.440+03:00] Validating the integrity of data file list...
[2018/05/29 12:05:01.679+03:00] Validation of data file list passed.
[2018/05/29 12:05:01.903+03:00][VERBOSE] Uploaded entities: 0    Downloaded blobs: 1 of 2, transferred bytes: 209 B
[2018/05/29 12:05:01.903+03:00][VERBOSE] Uploaded entities: 0    Downloaded blobs: 1 of 2, transferred bytes: 209 B
[2018/05/29 12:05:01.904+03:00][VERBOSE] Uploaded entities: 0    Downloaded blobs: 1 of 2, transferred bytes: 209 B
[2018/05/29 12:05:01.904+03:00][VERBOSE] Uploaded entities: 0    Downloaded blobs: 1 of 2, transferred bytes: 209 B
[2018/05/29 12:05:04.149+03:00][VERBOSE] Uploaded entities: 0    Downloaded blobs: 1 of 2, transferred bytes: 4 MB
[2018/05/29 12:05:23.741+03:00][VERBOSE] Uploaded entities: 0    Downloaded blobs: 1 of 2, transferred bytes: 8 MB
[2018/05/29 12:05:23.747+03:00][VERBOSE] Uploaded entities: 0    Downloaded blobs: 1 of 2, transferred bytes: 9.53 MB
[2018/05/29 12:05:23.753+03:00][VERBOSE] Uploaded entities: 0    Downloaded blobs: 1 of 2, transferred bytes: 9.53 MB
[2018/05/29 12:05:23.753+03:00][VERBOSE] Uploaded entities: 0    Downloaded blobs: 1 of 2, transferred bytes: 9.53 MB
[2018/05/29 12:05:23.756+03:00][VERBOSE] Uploaded entities: 0
[2018/05/29 12:05:23.823+03:00] Validating the integrity of data file "arenaxstorage_LeaderboardUser_0_0_C0DC932F526179D7.json"...
[2018/05/29 12:05:23.849+03:00] Validation of data file "arenaxstorage_LeaderboardUser_0_0_C0DC932F526179D7.json" passed.
[2018/05/29 12:05:26.463+03:00][VERBOSE] Uploaded entities: 100
[2018/05/29 12:05:27.667+03:00][VERBOSE] Uploaded entities: 500
...
[2018/05/29 12:08:18.882+03:00][VERBOSE] Uploaded entities: 21600
[2018/05/29 12:08:19.024+03:00][VERBOSE] Uploaded entities: 21704
[2018/05/29 12:08:19.040+03:00] 
Transfer summary:
-----------------
Total entities transferred: 21704
Elapsed time:               00.00:03:21
```

**Error**

```
[2018/05/29 12:10:44.537+03:00] >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
[2018/05/29 12:10:44.543+03:00][VERBOSE] 6.1.0 : AzCopy /Source:https://arenaxtablesbackup.blob.core.windows.net/arenaxstorage/2018-05-28 /Dest:https://arenaxstoragedev.table.core.windows.net/Leaderboard /SourceKey:****** /Destkey:****** /Manifest:arenaxstorage_Leaderboard.manifest /EntityOperation:InsertOrReplace /Z /V
[2018/05/29 12:10:47.659+03:00][VERBOSE] Uploaded entities: 0    Downloaded blobs: 1, transferred bytes: 205 B
[2018/05/29 12:10:47.895+03:00] Validating the integrity of data file list...
[2018/05/29 12:10:48.276+03:00][ERROR] Failed to import Azure table. Detailed error: Data validation failed. Data files are missing or have been renamed.
```

What is the problem?

Comment: When I exported this table to CSV and tried to import by Storage Explorer, I got the error "number of columns is inconsistent on line 53"
![image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/8911626/40711759-b41b5d44-6404-11e8-94d6-e73c36689f01.png)
Original table has additional columns starting this line:
![image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/8911626/40711922-0ae5ae54-6405-11e8-91c0-3178be50aff9.png)

Comment: When downloading the blobs that are failing locally, are you able to open them in the local Cosmos DB Emulator for troubleshooting purposes ?

Comment: I can download blobs without any problem and they are identically with that I make by running azcopy locally.

Comment: Are these blobs usable when downloading them ? The reason i'm asking is the error message you are getting is mainly caused by a corrupt file/blob

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your question. What's mean usable? I can open it by text editor or import by `Get-Content $FILE | ConvertFrom-Json`

Answer (score 0):

I found that import fails at the line starting from which a new columns was added to the table.

[image]

But I can import this table using Table Service REST API.
Is it possible to do the same with AzCopy somehow?